# Wordpress WPML plugin , get_terms returns data only for current language , i want it return for all available languages?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wpml

I'm using WPML Plugin v 4.4.9 and Wordpress v5.6.1

I want the **get_terms** function to return results for all available languages , ex : for **category** taxonomy (using some custom meta) , it only returns one result for the current language , how can i make it return result for all languages ?

Ex:

```
    $args = array(
    'suppress_filter' => true,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    //'meta_query' => $meta_queries,
    );
    
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy='category',$args);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how ,i'm saving your time here ,
i've spent 4 damn hours looking through the plugin and wpml forum ...

```
# please note is using category taxonomy by default, 
# you can specify other though , by calling the function with 2 params.

function get_terms_all_langs($taxonomy='category',$args=array()){

#based on menu troubleshooting.php
#https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/
#https://wpml.org/forums/topic/remove-get_terms-filters/

global $sitepress;

$has_get_terms_args_filter = remove_filter( 'get_terms_args', array( $sitepress, 'get_terms_args_filter' ) );
$has_get_term_filter       = remove_filter( 'get_term', array( $sitepress, 'get_term_adjust_id' ), 1 );
$has_terms_clauses_filter  = remove_filter( 'terms_clauses', array( $sitepress, 'terms_clauses' ) );
    
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy , $args );
    
if ( $has_terms_clauses_filter ) {
    add_filter( 'terms_clauses', array( $sitepress, 'terms_clauses' ), 10, 3 );
}
if ( $has_get_term_filter ) {
    add_filter( 'get_term', array( $sitepress, 'get_term_adjust_id' ), 1, 1 );
}
if ( $has_get_terms_args_filter ) {
    add_filter( 'get_terms_args', array( $sitepress, 'get_terms_args_filter' ), 10, 2 );
}

return $terms;
}
```

Sorting the above function results in array[lang] blocks , function example :

```
function group_cats_by_lang(){

$args = array('suppress_filter' => true,'hide_empty' => false);
$all_cats = get_terms_all_langs('category',$args); 

$ro_cats = array();
$fr_cats = array();
$en_cats = array();

foreach($all_cats as $cat_obj){

$language_code = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_language_code', null, array( 'element_id'=> (int)$cat_obj->term_id, 'element_type'=> 'category' ) );

if($language_code=="ro"){
$ro_cats['ro'][] = $cat_obj;
}

if($language_code=="fr"){
$fr_cats['fr'][] = $cat_obj;
}

if($language_code=="en"){
$en_cats['en'][] = $cat_obj;
}


}

return array($ro_cats,$fr_cats,$en_cats);

}
```